# Как в 1С поставить конкретным Основным средствам галочку?

Tags: 1с

Есть такой код:

```
Пока ВыборкаДокументов.Следующий() Цикл        
    Докум = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
    Для каждого СтрДок из Докум.ОсСред Цикл
        СтрДок.НаличиеФактическое = Истина;
        Сообщить(СтрДок.НаличиеФактическое);
    КонецЦикла;
    Докум.Записать(РежимЗаписиДокумента.Запись);
КонецЦикла;
```

Он ставит галочку всем основным средствам (пункт Фактическое наличие).

Как на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в 1С поставить конкретным Основным средствам галочку? (например, только для первого или второго основного средства)

Answer (score 0):

Флаг ставится так как вы построчно перебираете табличную часть документа и включаете его для каждой строки.

Самый простой способ - добавить условие в цикл:

```
Для каждого СтрДок из Докум.ОсСред Цикл
    // добавляем условие
    Если СтрДок.ОС = СпрОСЭлементПоиска Тогда  // писал по памяти, в СтрДок.ОС подставите свое имя реквизита
      СтрДок.НаличиеФактическое = Истина;
    КонецЕсли;

    Сообщить(СтрДок.НаличиеФактическое);
КонецЦикла;
```

Если вам требуется отобрать строки по нескольким условиям, например для перечня ОС, оптимальней использовать запрос и затем обработать отдельные строки.